# multiple Mapbox maps within a PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, mapbox-gl-js

I have a PHP foreach loop running through office locations.

I am trying to create a Mapbox map within the loop for each location (there are 5)

I can use the example from here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/marker-from-geocode/ to create a marker on the map using the location of the office.

I'm stuck with how to create this within the foreach so I can then have a map for each office location.

This is the code I have currently. I believe I am having an issue with variable naming or something similar as it's running over the same naming on each iteration of the loop????

**Just before loop**

```
    <script>
       mapboxgl.accessToken = 'mykey';
       const mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
     </script>
     <style>
        .map { height: 400px; width: 100%; }
     </style>
```

**Foreach Loop**

```
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 ps-5">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="mb-0">
              <b><?php echo $o->office_name; ?></b>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <address>
                <?php echo $o->office_building.'<br />'.$o->office_street.', '.$o->office_city.'<br />'.$o->office_county.'<br />'.$o->office_postcode; ?>
              </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
              <address>
                Tel: <?php echo $o->office_telephone; echo ($o->office_extension) ? ' ext:'.$o->office_extension : '';?><br />
                Fax: <?php echo $o->office_fax; ?><br />
                DX: <?php echo $o->office_DX; ?>
              </address>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="map<?php echo $o->office_id; ?>" class="map card-img-bottom border">

        </div>
        <script>
          mapboxClient.geocoding
          .forwardGeocode({
            query: '<?php echo 'Business Name, '.$o->office_building.', '.$o->office_street.', '.$o->office_city.' '.$o->office_county.', '.$o->office_postcode; ?>',
            autocomplete: false,
            limit: 1
          })
          .send()
          .then((response) => {
            if (
              !response ||
              !response.body ||
              !response.body.features ||
              !response.body.features.length
            ) {
              console.error('Invalid response:');
              console.error(response);
              return;
            }
          const feature = response.body.features[0];
          const map<?php echo $o->office_id; ?> = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map<?php echo $o->office_id; ?>',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: feature.center,
            zoom: 15
          });

          // Create a marker and add it to the map.
          new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(feature.center).addTo(map<?php echo $o->office_id; ?>);
          });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've updated the code above from @CBroe's answer below. I needed to have dynamic ID's for the various maps and move the styling for each map out of the foreach loop, changing it to a class rather than ID element.

Comment: You need to make this part `<div id="map"` and `container: 'map'` use dynamic, unique IDs as well.

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I've amended the code in the main question, sadly still not loading - I've got to be missing something here

Comment: `#map { height: 400px; width: 100%; }` probably needs changing as well, or does your map div get any height from somewhere else? (Recreating that same rule with the same values and only a different ID over and over again, would make rather less sense, I would replace it with one rule in your stylesheet that applies the formatting via class instead.)